# How do I categorize torrents in Deluge?

Tags: deluge

I'd like to assign custom labels to torrents the way I did in `µTorrent` for example. Or any other way to categorize them. As far as I can [tell](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins), there must be `Label` plugin bundled with `deluge`, but does it really work? I don't see any way to assign labels. If not, are there other torrent clients able to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can use the `Label` plugin to do this.

**Enable** the plugin by opening `Preferences`, navigating to the Plugins page and ticking the `Label` plugin:

[image]

**Create** a label (or modify it options) by right-clicking on the `Labels` section in the sidebar:

[image]

**Assign** a label to a torrent by right-clicking on the selected torrent(s) and then select your label from the sub-menu:

[image]

---

The Label plugin is included with Deluge but there is also a more powerful third party plugin [LabelPlus](http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=42629) with the following features:

- Sublabels
- Less restrictive label names
- Ability to rename labels
- Relative move completed paths
- Auto-labeling based on torrent name or tracker
- Limit torrent speed by label

  [Download LabelPlus](https://github.com/ratanakvlun/deluge-labelplus/releases)

Comment: I realized, I have to enable this plugin first in `Preferences`. Thanks a lot :) I believe it makes sense to add this information to your answer.

Comment: Also note that adding a label with spaces in the name seems to just not do anything. I realized after looking at the image above  why my label was not being made.

Comment: "Create a label by right-clicking on the Labels section in the sidebar" That's a good hiding place. It almost seems like he doesn't want you to find this.

Comment: I have searched for ages on how to create labels and assign location. Your answer helped a lot!  +1 for Andreas! ;)